# Google UI Script validateMatches doesn't work, validateNotMatches does

Tags: validation, google-apps-script

I am designing a form using Google Scripting. I have two text boxes that need to hold time values, and I want to make sure the input is valid.

```
function setupTimeValidators(widget) {
  var timeRe = /(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ?[ap]m/i;

  var onValid = (UiApp.getActiveApplication().createClientHandler()
                 .validateMatches(widget, timeRe)
                 .forTargets(widget)
                 .setStyleAttribute("background", "#FFFFFF"));


  var onInvalid = (UiApp.getActiveApplication().createClientHandler()
                   .validateNotMatches(widget, timeRe)
                   .forTargets(widget)
                   .setStyleAttribute("background", "#FFCCCC"));

  widget.addKeyUpHandler(onValid);
  widget.addKeyUpHandler(onInvalid);
}
```

The `onInvalid` parts changes the textbox background color as soon as I start typing in the textbox, but it never changes back to white when I get to `01:11 pm`. (I have tested this with other values.)

I am sure my regular expression works, because I tested it like so:

```
function test() {
  Browser.msgBox(/(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ?[ap]m/i.test("01:11 pm")); // true
  Browser.msgBox(/(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ?[ap]m/i.test("00:11 pm")); // false
  Browser.msgBox(/(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ?[ap]m/i.test("10:11 pm")); // true
  Browser.msgBox(/(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ?[ap]m/i.test("10:90 pm")); // false
}
```

Any ideas what could be going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a regex object with validateMatches or validateNotMatches.. you should use a string representation of the regex, as such:

```
var timeRe = "(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ?[ap]m";
var flags = "i";
```

...

```
.validateMatches(widget, timeRe, flags)
```

Comment: That did it, thank you! (It helps when I read the documentation correctly...)